# Undefined reference cuando llamo a una funcion en ARM desde C

Tags: c, compilador, arm

```
.extern tratar_excepcion

.global exception_data_abort

exception_data_abort:
mov r0, #1
b tratar_excepcion
```

En el primer archivo lo que hago es desclarar la función en ensamblador que va a tratar la interrupcion y lo que va a hacer, va a mover un 1 a un registro y luego saltara a una función en c.

```
void exception_data_abort(void);
void configurar_interrupciones() {
pISR_DABORT = (unsigned) exception_data_abort;
}

void tratar_excepcion(int tipo){
D8Led_symbol(tipo);
while(1);
 }
```

En el segundo archivo, asigno a la interrupción ABORT la función definida arriba para que cuando se produzca una interrupción de ese tipo, se ejecute esa instrucción.

Cuando compilo me da un fallo de undefined reference to `exception_data_abort'

Y no se porqué.

Comment: La pregunta obvia: ¿ como lo estás compilando + enlazando ?

Comment: Estoy usando `arm-none-eabi-gcc` para compilar y enlazar

Comment: ¿ Pero como lo estás haciendo ? [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/212929/edit) y la pregunta y detalla los pasos y comandos exactos, por favor :-)

Comment: No estoy usando comandos estoy usando Eclipse